# Conditional object properties in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to use conditional statements (&& or ?) inside an object that is returned within method in React component. Is it possible?
The issue is I want to add to condition multiple properties. It works with just one like this:

```
      arr: [
          isInsidePlan 
              ? {
                label: 'anything1'
                value: 1,
              } :
              {
                label: 'anything2'
                value: 2,
              },
          {
            label: 'anything3'
            value: 3,
          },
          {
            label: 'anything4'
            value: 4,
          },
    ],
```

What I would like to achieve is to do it with all other properties inside `else` condition. Like this: (this code doesn't work)

```
arr: [
  isInsidePlan 
      ? ({
        label: 'anything1'
        value: 1,
      }) :
      ({
        label: 'anything2'
        value: 2,
      },
      {
        label: 'anything3'
        value: 3,
      },
      {
        label: 'anything4'
        value: 4,
      })
],
```

I get an error:

> Left side of comma operator is unused and has no side effects.

Answer (score 0):

You should make the `if` condition outside the array itself.

Something like:

```
arr: isInsidePlan ? [
      {
        label: 'anything1'
        value: 1,
      }] :
      [{
        label: 'anything2'
        value: 2,
      },
      {
        label: 'anything3'
        value: 3,
      },
      {
        label: 'anything4'
        value: 4,
      }]
],
```